# Get specific string from specific point of line

Tags: shell-script, grep

From the below line I need specific fields only in following format:

```
031100000080,Z45G0001,09:43:08.5234999,09:43:09.7925597,0:1:269,737683
```

Input line:

```
17/05/2019 09:43:09.792559|TraceDetail    |UPBSStandardGenericBillPaymentComponent.PostBillPaymentTransacti|Total Time [125456]                   |783562  [11] [25458]            | Consumer Number [0345454545000             ] , UCID [Z456G0001]  Sending Time [09:43:08.5234999] Receive Time [09:43:09.7925597] Total Time [0:1:269] STAN is [737683]
```

Comment: The first number 031100000080 is nowhere to be found in your string. Please edit your question to include more of your input, aswell as your expected output.

Comment: If you only need to do this for one line, you've done it. If you need to do this for several lines, what's common between these lines?

Comment: @Panki It only says "following format", not "desired output", so there is good reason to suppose it's the Consumer Number

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your input through

```
sed 's/][^[]*\[/,/g;s/\([^,]*,\)\{3\}//;s/  *,/,/;s/]$//'
```

- `s/][^[]*\[/,/g` does most of the job by removing everything between the `[]` and separating it with comma
- `s/\([^,]*,\)\{3\}//` gets rid of the first fields you don't use
- `s/  *,/,/` strips the obsolete spaces
- `s/]$//'` finally removes the last `]`

**Update:**
Your comment suggests, that the number and order of fields may be different in each line. In this case a more general approach by appending the field names to each line and loop to extract the according fields:

```
sed -e 'G;s/$/,Consumer Number,UCID,Sending Time,Receive Time,Total Time,STAN is,/;:loop' -e 's/ \(.*\) \[\([^] ]*\)\(.*\n.*,\)\1,/\3\2,/;tloop' -e 's/.*\n,//;s/,$//'
```

I can give a more detailled explanation if this is really what you are looking for.

Comment: Format can be change in other lines so it shouldn't be constant like get string from bracket or from index.
Extract data from line when Consumer Number arrives and when UCID and Sending Time and Receive Time and Total Time and STAN is.

Comment: @user354005 ^^ then please provide more example data so we can see the differences that our code needs to handle.